# Has each... how natural is it?

Tags: perfect-constructions

Ahoy, folks.

I wonder if it's natural and widely accepted to use 'has' in perfect structures, such as those given below:

> Has each member of the committee provided feedback on the proposal?
>
> Has each employee attended the mandatory training sessions?
>
> Has each COVID-19 day at home become ground hog day?

In my understanding **they're ok**, but I couldn't find any trustful source reiterating my train of thought.

Some said me I could use 'Does each of you', but it doesn't work with PP.

Thank you.

Comment: Has X provided Y?  Did X provide Y? Has X attended Y? Did X attend Y?  Has X become Y? Did X become Y?

Comment: hmmm.. But what's the problem with 'each'?

Comment: There is no problem with "each".  Why do you think its a problem?

Comment: you corrected my sentences without the use of 'each'

Comment: It doesn't make any difference.  Each is singular.  Each X is singular. Each of my bananas is singular.  Each of you is singular. Each of them is singular.

Comment: Forgive me, but my question is more about proofreading than grammar. I know it makes sense grammatically, but I'm not sure if it sounds good to the ears.

Comment: "Each" is perfectly fine, but I hear "every" or "all" more often in sentences similar to ones you provided.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your sentences.  You can use did/does/do to ask questions, but you would need to use the base form of the verb, not the past participle.  E.g. Does he eat bananas? Did he eat bananas?  Does each banana taste good? Do you like bananas? Does each of you like bananas? Did each of you like bananas? Did you like bananas?

Comment: Ok! Thank you all for answering me <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct way to phrase the question when the answer would be either "Yes, each member of the committee has provided feedback," or "No, each member of the committee has not provided feedback."  If you feel it's awkward, you could rephrase as "Have we gotten feedback from each member of the committee?" which would mean the same thing.

Comment: Note that "gotten" is considered non-standard/dialect/regional in some varieties of English.

Comment: Okay, if that is of concern, then "received" would be an acceptable substitute, although I don't think it's dialect in this type of usage, since you get feedback from the people who give it.

Comment: It is dialect - it's your American dialect (American English). All varieties of English are a dialect though, so don't feel bad.;)

Comment: No; I don't feel bad.  I replied as I did because while I know that to use "got" instead of "have" is a dialectic usage, that was not the case here.

Comment: Sorry, it's not your use of "got" that I was talking about. It's your use of "gotten".  It's mainly used in American English, and is considered non-standard/dialect/regional for example, in standard British English.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Thanks for the info.  What do they use instead?

Comment: We just use **got**, e.g.  I have just got a new car.  - Well, I wish . . . LOL

Comment: I find "each member has not provided feedback" a little awkward, because I am not sure whether it means that no members have provided feedback or that only some members have provided feedback. I would prefer the negative response to be "No, not every member of the committee has provided feedback."

Comment: Well, I see your point, but OP did reference the use of "has each," and I just used parallel grammatical construction to word the answer to match the question asked.  If you leave off the "no" of my ,"no, each member..." reply, it does make it awkward, but when you start with the "no" and reword your reply to match the language used in the person's question, it's not awkward.